# How to convert an integer to date_time?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I have a number for average time. I want to return time format like "00:00:12"
How can i do it?

```
a_function(){

  $sum_duration = Model::where('as_user_id',$this->id)->sum('duration');
  //sum_duration = 21
  $week_count = $first_impression->created_at->diffInWeeks($last_impression->created_at);
  //week_count = 2

  $time = date_create(round($sum_duration / ($week_count == 0? 1:$week_count)));
  //false

  return date_format( $time,"H:i:s");
}
```

The above code is not working. 
How can i change to show time format like 00:00:00 ((`H:i:s`))

Comment: is this duration in hours?

Comment: this duration shows seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the duration is in minutes. You can use [gmdate()](https://www.php.net/gmdate) method to format it.

Example:

```
gmdate("H:i:s", 123) // returns 00:02:03
```

Comment: 123 minutes are 2 minutes and 3 seconds? Even if you meant seconds, `gmdate("H:i:s", 86400)` prints `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have `Carbon`;

```
$sum_duration = 21; // from your calculation
$week_count = 2; // from your calculation
$default = Carbon::now()->setTime(0, 0); // set as 00:00:00
$difference = round($sum_duration / ($week_count == 0 ? 1 : $week_count)); // your calculation
$default->addSeconds($difference); // add seconds to 00:00:00

return $default->format('H:i:s');
```

Edited for `seconds`

Comment: wonderful, i suggest : $default->addSeconds($difference);  (addSeconds with s)

Comment: @OMR yes you are right, ide auto-completed. Updated for seconds after seeing the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Durations aren't dates. But it's an easy calculation nonetheless:

```
printf('%02d:%02d:%02d', floor($seconds / 3600), floor($seconds / 60 % 60), $seconds % 60);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/K17vi)

(Switch to `sprintf()` if you want to store or return the value).